# heap corruption detected. c plus plus

Tags: c++, dynamic, runtime

I get heap corruption when I run this code.I don't know what the problem is.
ERROR: HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block.

```
unsigned int a_or_c_checker(char* a, char* b,int n)
{
    unsigned int ans = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if ((a[j]-48) && (b[j]-48)) ans *= 2;
        if ((a[j] - 48) && !(b[j] - 48))    return 0;
        ans %= 1000000007;
    }
    return ans;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    unsigned int * res = new unsigned int[t];
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        char * a = new char[n];
        char * b = new char[n];
        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;
        res[i] = a_or_c_checker(a, b, n); // heap corruption
        delete[] a;
        delete[] b;
    }
    delete[] res;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) What's your input? 2) Did you try, stepping through your code, with a debugger?

Comment: 1)3
2
10
11
3
110
110
4
1110
1011

Comment: 2)yes i have.everything was ok.the function returned 2

Comment: Oh, I wrote my comment, and then realized, what do you think `cin >> a;` does?

Comment: gets string a from the user

Comment: And, is that string, exactly the same length, as you specified in your input? E.g. in the first case: `2 10 11`. Is `10`, when being read as a character string, needs a buffer to store **only** 2 characters? EDIT: the heap corruption is not in the function, but rather at `delete`. If you would've used debugger, you would know that.

Comment: yes.that part doesn't have a problem.the error happens when it wants to store data in res[0].

Comment: The correct answer to my initial question is: no. C-strings always end with `\0` character, hence, needing n+1 characters to store it. Hence, `cin` writes past the bound of the array resulting in UB. In C++, you should consider using `std::string`, and `std::vector` to avoid these sorts of problems..

Comment: well, that is completely true.but I can't find the relation between this problem and the heap problem here because the 'res' is int and the problem happens with 'res'

Comment: What? I told you what the problem is, and then you dismiss it, since it manifests itself in the wrong place? It's UB - undefined behaviour. Anything could happen. And, speaking from experience, heap corruptions very rarely manifests itself in the place, where it is, actually, happening. For example: for me, it manifests itself when trying to `delete`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Please excuse me

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `std::string`, rather than trusting the user's input for the length.

Also remember that the c string "abc" needs char[4] to store it, because it is null terminated and must store the hidden null character.

```
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
{ 
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    int n = min(a.length(), b.length())
    res[i] = a_or_c_checker(a.c_str(), b.c_str(), n);
}
```